# Else if loop not executing

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have done this code in `c#` for my project and I when I try to execute this I'll get -ve numbers. I don't want a number less than zero. That's why I added the `else if` loop in it. But still its not working. Please help.

```
 if (myString.Contains(input))
 {
     int pos1 = myString.IndexOf(input);
     int tpos = pos - pos1;
     if (tpos < 20)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("You're Safe", "Important Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
         MessageBox.Show(tpos.ToString());
     }
     else if (tpos < 0)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("You are Vulnerable", "Critical Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("You are Vulnerable", "Critical Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
     }
 }
```

Comment: If a value is < 0, don't you think it will also be less than 20?

Comment: I just got the answer now. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `else if` above the `if`, like this:

```
if (tpos < 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You are Vulnerable", "Critical Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }

else if (tpos < 20)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You're Safe", "Important Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    MessageBox.Show(tpos.ToString());
                }
```

In your code, if a number was negative, it satisfied the first `if` condition, and therefore never entered the `else if` condition. Now, if a number is negative, it will be checked in the first condition itself.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the conditions. The first condition is always true for numbers less than zero.

Comment: You might want to change some of the words around in your last sentence there... ;)